# Spring Mvc, how to override beans definition by annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

i have a web application (webapp1) with two services, each service inherits from an interface. Each service has the annotation @SERVICE with an id. (service1 and service2). 
For example for wervice1, i've got :

```
@SERVICE("service1")
```

Each service is injected in controller by using `@AUTOWIRED` and `@QUALIFIER` annotation.
Now i have a second web application (webapp2) which is made by overlay on webapp1.
In webapp2, i want to override service1. I try to do this :

```
@PRIMARY
@SERVICE("service1")
```

I've got an error because i've got two beans with the same id (service1 and the wervice which override service1).

The error message is : `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'service1' for bean class [fr.yyy.oav.xxx.service.YyyService1] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [fr.harvest.oav.xxx.service.XxxService1]`

I tried to use the annotation @Bean which permits to use names instead of id be spring forbids to use it on a class.

Is there a way to override service1 without using xml definition?

thanks

Comment: Could you show the full error message?

Comment: Try to autowire (resolve) beans by type; hence you won't need an id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `autowire="bytype"` in your specified bean tag .Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I can't use it because service1 and service2 (both in the same webapp) implements the same interface so they are both inject by using the type of interface. It's why i use id on qualifier to distinguish them.